# Why do some commercial aircraft have no landing gear cover?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, landing-gear, boeing-737, drag

The B737 has no cover on its landing gear, as may be seen in this picture. Doesn't this increase the air drag?

[image]

Almost all other airliners have doors that close off the rubber of the wheels, for example this B787.

[image]

Why doesn't the B737 have a cover on its landing gear?

Comment: @anshabhi Thanks for the edits

Comment: The 737's hubcap _is_ its landing gear door.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it does increase drag.  Anything that is not smooth, where the air flow will be disturbed, will generate drag.

The 737 was originally designed only for short haul and space is at a premium.  Adding doors and all the associated mechanisms adds complexity, weight, additional maintenance requirements and more possibilities for failure.

Boeing have had many opportunities to add doors and have chosen not to; so they, and their customers, do not see the drag penalty as more expensive than the extra weight and maintenance.